# Sidekiq Worker Options Based on Queue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sidekiq

I have a queue in Sidekiq named `crawlers` and a bunch of workers for all the specific crawling jobs I need done. The question is how to set `sidekiq_options` for all the workers in this queue.

For example, I don't want them to retry and I want to handle errors in a particular way. Is this possible in a Sidekiq-native way? Without creating a base `CrawlerWorker` class and inheriting from it?